# List files in your home directory

Tags: ls

Im having trouble figuring out that, if I'm in let say the directory /home/test/test2 but I want to find the number of files in the /home directory, how would I do it.

I know how to do it if it was the other way around, like in your home directory, list files in /home/test/test2, you would do:

```
ls /home/test/test2 | wc -l
```

but how would I do it if I was in the test2 directory and wanted to find the number of files in the home directory.

Thanks

Comment: (1) Why does your question title say “List” when you seem to be asking about *counting*?  (2) Do you mean ***your*** home directory, or do you mean the `/home` directory?  (Or *is* `/home` your home directory??)  (3) Do you know how to refer to your home directory on the command line?  (Hint: `"$HOME"` is one way, typing it out (e.g., `/home/shawn`) is another, and there’s an even better way.)  (4) If you’re asking about `/home`, why don’t you think `ls /home | wc -l` will work?  If you’re asking about your home directory, can you figure it out from what I’ve just said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From any where If you want to find how many files in your home directory

This is the command

```
ls -la ~/ | wc -l
```

Example:

```
virt01@virt01:~/test$ ls -la ~/ | wc -l
25
virt01@virt01:~/test$
```

There `~/` is pointing to current login users Home directory

Comment: how about other files then my home directory. Like what if im in /home/test/test2 but want to find out how many files are in /home/example/example2

Comment: You can use `~/example/example2`

Comment: No , ~/ is home directory and example is another directory and example2 is another one inside of example

Comment: @Sukminder stop arguing mate virt01@virt01:~/test$ ls ~/
chef-repo  jboss-5.1.0.GA  jbossatwork-1.0.2  jdk1.8.0_65  New directory  Python_Admin  some.txt  test  test1  text.txt  typescript
virt01@virt01:~/test$

Comment: `/home`  is the parent directory for all users, or *homes*. `/home/test` is home or ~ for user *test*. `/home/example` is home or ~ for user *example*.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `..` to point to the directory behind your current.

E.g.

```
User@~/test/test2:$ ls ../ | wc -l # here you'll list the 'test' directory content

User@~/test/test2:$ ls ../../ | wc -l # here you'll list the 'home' directory content
```

Each `..` will jump to one dir behind